# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input in line 20

Tags: ruby

I am very new to ruby and had written the code on encapsulation.But facing the error as "syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input in line 20".Can any one help me to know on what base I am getting the error

```
Class Employee
  def empdetails(name,empid,age,department)
    @name=name
    @empid=empid
    @age=age
    @department=department
  end

  def empname
    return @name
  end

  def empid
    return @empid
  end

  def empage
    return @age
  end

  def empdeparmtnet
    return @department
  end
end
empobj=Employee.new
empobj.empdetails("tom","522001","28","IT")
puts(empobj.empname)
```

Comment: Usually means there are already too many `end` or `}` tokens.

Answer (score 2):

In ruby `class` keyword should be in lowercase.

```
class Employee
  def empdetails(name,empid,age,department)
    @name=name
    @empid=empid
    @age=age
    @department=department
  end

  def empname
    return @name
  end

  def empid
    return @empid
  end

  def empage
    return @age
  end

  def empdeparmtnet
    return @department
  end
end
empobj=Employee.new
empobj.empdetails("tom","522001","28","IT")
puts(empobj.empname)
```

Comment: Dear Shan ,       I had changes the keyword with lower case,But don't find any luck

Comment: Its simple. just lowercase your `class` keyword. I have updated the answer. please accept the answer if it works.